# Remover Packet TClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

Olá.

Tenho um TClientDataSet, e no mesmo defino o parâmetro `FetchOnDemand := False` e `PacketRecords := 10`;

No evento `AfterScroll` chamo `GetNextPacket`, e desta maneira tenho o controle por demanda dos dados.

Porém, se eu tiver uma tabela muito grande, e for até o último registro, ao dar um `Refresh` pode acabar demorando muito.

Desta maneira, gostaria de saber se tem como eu remover um pacote no momento de solicitar outro, ou seja, quando chamar o `GetNextPacket`.